# ListField In Django - Python

Tags: django, django-models

I want to store multiple CharField values in a list of a model. Is there any way to do it?
I was expecting something like

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birth = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    quote = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    books = models.ListField(
        book_name = CharField(max_length=255)
    )
```

Apparently Django does not provide anything similiar.

Comment: If you use PostgreSQL then you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into foreign fields and defining a `Book` model like the following

```py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birth = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    quote = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=2083)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```